# Navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have such ViewControllers [image]

After registration user is moved to RevealViewController

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = (SWRevealViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"revealViewControllerID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:revealViewController animated:YES];
```

and then goes to Main View Controller with own top bar, but it is not shown, because there appears navigation bar with 'back button' (see image). How can i remove this navigation bar to see my top bar?

I found a lot of SO pages with similar question, but no one solution has been able to remove navigation bar.

Comment: Or present the RegistrationView modally, then dismiss when registered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the following method:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

into your

`- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`